# chai-http response is always undefined

Tags: mocha.js, chai, chai-http

i'm try to run this test but the res is always undifined , its weird because when i try it from postman its work fine

my test:

```
const { chai, assert, should, expect, sinon } = require("../baseTest");

 describe.only("Test the Default routes", function() {
  const server = 'http://localhost:3000';
  this.timeout(20000); 
  it("test the / route", (done) => {
     chai
      .request(server) 
       .get("/") 
       .end(function (err, res) {
         console.log(res);
         expect(err).to.be.null; 
        expect(res).to.have.status(200); 
        done();
      }); 
   }); 
});
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Server is not correct, import server from your node app main file

Comment: agree,but in [chai-http site](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) under the URL title they say that it possible.....

Comment: Are you sure that application server is running and listening to same port

Comment: yes.the test is running ok when i switch the server to my node server as you said.....but i steel prefer to work with `server = 'http://localhost:3000';`

Comment: then use axios, It will work

Comment: thanks for your time

Comment: If you are still with this issue: Are you sure your server is up when you run the test?